# Docker plugin in Jenkins - Override workspace mount place

Tags: docker, jenkins, pipeline, docker-container

In Jenkins pipeline, when I use `withDockerContainer()` or `docker.build(...).inside(...)`, the jenkins workspace is automatically mounted into the container in the same place (ex. if jenkins worksapce was /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name, then a mount point of this path will be added to the container in the same path `-v /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name:/tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name -w /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name`.

I want to override the path were the workspace is mounted inside the container. I do the following `docker.build(...).inside("-v $WORKSPACE:/tmp/ws -w /tmp/ws")` however when I look in to the console, I see that the container is created as following (assuming that the current workspace in the stage is /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name@1
`docker run -d -v /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name@1:/tmp/ws -w /tmp/ws -e ******* -e ******* -v /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name@1:/tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name@1 -w /tmp/jenkins_ws/job_name@1 IMAGE_NAME cat`

Note that the command contains the arguments that I passed in the `.inside()` method and then the plugin appends some stuff again.

I want to be able to mount the workspace into some place in the container that overrides the default place.

For those who are interested in why I need to do this, cmake generates only absolute paths in the Makefiles so I cannot move the build tree into a different place. What I am doing here is that I build in a stage in a container and I want to test the bits in multiple stages in parallel and but guarantee that the workspace path in the containers is always the same.

Comment: did you solve the problem? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I did not really solve it but what you can do is either run the docker command manually "docker run -ti ..." or create a symbolic link inside the container pointing to the real workspace